# django- createview with url parameter shows error

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-templates

I have a view AsignacionGeneral from where I call the view assignacion_contact with `href="{% url 'gestionAsignacion:assignacion_contact' pk=asig.id %}` and pass the parameter by url which is the primary key to be inserted later in the foreign key `idasignacion_general = models.ForeignKey('AsignacionGeneral', models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='idasignacion_general')` , the view assignacion_contact has a form, it opens fine, I fill the form but when I send it I want it to stay in the same view.
example: I am in the url "assignation/assignationContact/1", the pk=1 , I take that value and assign it to the Foreign Key, I fill the form with the data but when I send it it redirects me to 'assignation/assignationContact' which does not exist and I want it to stay in the url ' 'asignacion/asignacionContact/1'

[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kp0D6.png)

url.py

```
app_name = 'gestionAsignacion'

urlpatterns = [
     
    path('asignacionContact/<int:pk>',AsignacionCreateView.as_view(), name='asignacion_contact'),
    path('detalle/asignacion/<int:pk>',descargarAsignacion.as_view(), name='descargar_asignacion'),
    path('asignacionGeneral/',asignacionGeneral.as_view(), name='asignacion_general'),
]
```

view.py

```
class AsignacionCreateView(CreateView):
    model=AsignacionContact
    form_class=AsignacionForm
    template_name='gestionAsignacion/asignacion_contact.html'
    # success_url = reverse_lazy('gestionAsignacion:asignacion_general')
    
    def get_initial(self):
        # call super if needed
       
        return {'idasignacion_general': self.kwargs['pk']}

    def form_valid(self, form):
        print('hola form_valid')
        isvalid = super().form_valid(form)
        return isvalid


   
    def get_success_url(self):
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('gestionAsignacion:asignacion_general'))


    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        # Llame primero a la implementación base para obtener un contexto
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
       
        # Agregar un QuerySet de todos los libros
        context['asig_general'] = AsignacionGeneral.objects.get(id=self.kwargs['pk'])
        context['object_list'] = AsignacionContact.objects.filter(idasignacion_general=self.kwargs['pk'])
        
        return context
```

model.py

```
class AsignacionContact(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    idasignacion_general = models.ForeignKey('AsignacionGeneral', models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='idasignacion_general')
    nombre_asignacion = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    fecha_inicio = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    fecha_fin = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    observacion = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.nombre_asignacion
    class Meta:
         managed = False
         db_table = 'asignacion_contact'
```

form.py

```
class AsignacionForm(ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(AsignacionForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        for field in iter(self.fields):
            self.fields[field].widget.attrs.update({
                'class': 'form-control'
            })
    class Meta:
        model=AsignacionContact
        fields=['idasignacion_general','nombre_asignacion','fecha_inicio','fecha_fin','observacion']
```

Answer (score 0):

This `path('asignacionContact/<int:pk>',...` means that the primary key of the object is required to show the view.

For example, an object with `pk=1` would work for the URL path `asignacion/asignacionContact/1`.

You don't have a view that's just `asignacion/asignacionContact/` in your urls.py.

That's why you are getting a Page not found (404).

I think you think `<int:pk>` in urls.py are `GET` *querystrings*. They are not. They are required URL values. `GET` parameters appear appended to the URL for example if you were to submit a form with a `method="GET"`. The form data would appear in the URL.

Comment: I have a view `AsignacionGeneral` from where I call the view `assignacion_contact` with `href="{% url 'gestionAsignacion:assignacion_contact' pk=asig.id %}` and pass the parameter which is the primary key to be inserted later in the foreign key `idasignacion_general = models.ForeignKey('AsignacionGeneral', models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='idasignacion_general')` , the view `assignacion_contact` has a form, it opens fine, I fill the form but when I send it I want it to stay in the same view.

Comment: example: I am in the url "assignation/assignationContact/1", the pk=1 , I take that value and assign it to the Foreign Key, I fill the form with the data but when I send it it redirects me to 'assignation/assignationContact' which does not exist and I want it to stay in the url ' 'asignacion/asignacionContact/1'

Comment: Are you just trying to update an existing db record (ex: pk=1)? If so, you wouldn't update an existing record from a CreateView.

Comment: no,  insert into table asignacion_contact

Comment: Sorry, I tried really hard to understand your question but I don't. I would remove: `get_initial`, `form_valid`, and `get_success_url` from your class and add a `get_absolute_url` to your model. If that doesn't work, copy the methods from [here](https://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/4.0/django.views.generic.edit/CreateView/) into your class and set breakpoints to debug each step of the way to see what's going on.